# Disable\Enable multiple checkboxes in Kendo UI TreeList

Tags: jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui, disabled-input, kendo-treelist

I tried these solutions for disable\enable multiple checkboxes in Kendo UI TreeList when header checkbox is clicked:

1.prop('disabled',true) \ prop('disabled',false)

2.attr('disabled','disabled') \ removeAttr('disabled');

3.$(...)[0].disabled=true \ $(...)[0].disabled=false

But all of them has the same problem which affects just the last item in the TreeList !!!

I really confused and don't know what is going wrong, is it possible to be resolved?

Comment: *"is it possible to be resolved"* yes, probably, but we need more info about how your treeview is built and checkboxes rendered, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over all your checkboxes.

For the checking itself, prop is the way to go.